# Use a Variable in a different Scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my GameScene I have a variable called "score" which I want to use in the MenuScene to display the latest score. I have tried it with the UserDefaults but I didn't really understand it and it didn't work. Could someone tell me how I have to declare the score variable so I can use it in other scenes, and it would also be nice if someone could show me a way how to save a variable so I can save the highscore.

I've tried this:

GameScene:

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard // Before didMove func
UserDefaults.setValue(score, forKey: "Score") // in gameOver func
```

MenuScene:

```
var score = SKLabelNode()
var scoreNumber = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Score")
```

If I run the Game it loads the MenuScene and I can press on play and it goes to the GameScene. If I die in the GameScene, the game crashes and i get this error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Score.'"

Comment: UserDefaults should work. Show what you have tried and you will likely get your answer. Or just use search, there are many answers alread about that topic.

Comment: I used score = UserDefaults.standard
score.set("String", forKey"Score")
But as I said i didn't really understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use user defaults correctly you should be able to read and write from any object as `UserDefaults.standard` is a singleton. Something along these lines should work:

```
private let scoreUserDefaultsKey = "scoreUserDefaultsKey"

func save(score: Int)
{
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.set(score, forKey: scoreUserDefaultsKey)
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}

func read() -> Int
{
    return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: scoreUserDefaultsKey)
}

class GameScene1: SKScene {

    func saveFromGameScene1(score: Int) {
        save(score: score)
    }
}

class GameScene2: SKScene {

    func readFromGameScene2() -> Int {
        return read()
    }
}
```

Said that you could have a much nicer architecture implementing a ScoreManager object and inject it (instead of having hard dependencies on a singleton) into your game scenes.

**UPDATE:**
Just seen your code snippet. You need to use `set`, not `setValue`. `setValue` is not a method of UserDefaults but is a method of NSObject for KVO.

> func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String)
>
> Sets the property of the receiver specified by a given key to a given
>   value. If key identifies a to-one relationship, relate the object
>   specified by value to the receiver, unrelating the previously related
>   object if there was one. Given a collection object and a key that
>   identifies a to-many relationship, relate the objects contained in the
>   collection to the receiver, unrelating previously related objects if
>   there were any.
>
> The search pattern that setValue:forKey: uses is described in Accessor
>   Search Patterns in Key-Value Coding Programming Guide.
>
> In a reference-counted environment, if the instance variable is
>   accessed directly, value is retained.

That is not what you're looking for ;)

Also after you call `set` make sure to call `synchronize` as well to be certain that the value is stored immediately.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I know have in the GameOver function in the GameScene "UserDefaults.setValue(score, forKey: "Score")" and in the MenuScene "var score = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Score")" but when i test the game, the first time i switch from the GameScene to the MenuScene, i get this error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSUserDefaults 0x1a7b9ff88> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Score." what did i do wrong?

Comment: Let me know if my updated answer solves your problem.

Comment: Yes, it did solve my problem thank you very much. So the score saved if i end the app and run it again, right?

Comment: Yes it is persistent. It will get deleted either if you explicitly do so in code or you delete and then reinstall the app (it will persist in app updates as the app doesn't get deleted).

Comment: @LukasDomeisen Could you please accept the answer if it does solve your problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could just move your `var gameScore` from being global, meaning removing it from `GameScene` , and make it universal by moving it in between `import SpriteKit` and `class GameScene`. After that, you could just use `NSUserDefault` just as the others have suggested.

UPDATE

ok so for my GameOver scenes, i usually do something like this within the class

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults()
var highScoreNumber = defaults.integerForKey("highScoreSaved")

If gameScore > highScoreNumber{
highScoreNumber = gameScore
defaults.setInteger(highScoreNumber, forKey: "highScoreSaved")
  }
```

You can just do this in your MenuScene instead.

Comment: The problem is, I don't know how to use the UserDefault and i also can't find anything online.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dynamic variable in difference viewcontroller. And use it all the time. You make create in Appdelegate.

In your AppDelegate.swift

```
    var yourVariableName: Any = "Value"
```

When you wanna use it or change it. You

```
    let app: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    print(app.youVariableName)
```

If you wanna observe the variable value change and do some Action. You make setting up a didSet function.

```
var yourVariableName: Any = "VALUE" {didSet{observeValueChangeFunction()}}
func didSet{observeValueChangeFunction() {
     print("New value: \(yourVariableName)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use UserDefaults to do this,

first reason that I wanna ask you, if someone close the app, maybe they kill the app when they are playing, how you make the deal with the score?

Definitely, you should not keep this score, right? or you should cache all data of the game, then when the player goes into the game again, you could back to the state when the app was closed. But I think it is so complex to do this.

So I think you should put this score globally or easier to control this is just pass the score from the `GameScene` to the maybe called `ResultScene`.

I do suppose your game have these scenes:
`LoginScene` `MapScene` `GameScene` `ResultScene` `RankScene`

so you just use the score in the `GameScene` and `ResultScene` in real time, so you just do this in the `GameScene`:

```
var score   : Int/CGFloat     = 0;
func enterFrame(){
   //if they got the goal, then
   // score = score + 1 or much more;
}

func gameOver(){
   let resultScene = ResultScene(score: score);
   // or you could just create the empty ResultScene, and pass the score via a public func of the ResultScene
}
```

then you could show the score in the `ResultScene`.

if you are just making a server-less game, you should keep the scores into the `UserDefaults` or `CoreData` or `SQLite` etc.
then you can show the scores in some scenes about the `history records`.